# How to add a table to dictionary from a given text file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Say we have two text files containing each a table like:

table1.txt

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
b: 4
```

table2.txt

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
b: 5
```

I would like to add those tables into Python dictionaries and then compare the entries so that I dump the mismatching result in output file. In the example above

output.txt

```
b:4 | b:5
```

Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each file, and for each of their lines add them as entries in a dictionary. In the end, compare the entries of both dictionaries, and write to the file those entries that mismatch.

```
def count_words(file, dict):
    for line in file:
        key_value = line.split(":")
        key = key_value[0]
        dict[key] = key_value[1].strip()


dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
with open("table1.txt", "r") as file1:
    with open("table2.txt", "r") as file2:
        count_words(file2, dict2)
    count_words(file1, dict1)


with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for k in dict1:
        if dict1[k] != dict2[k]:
            f.write("{0}:{1} | {0}:{2}\n".format(k, dict1[k], dict2[k]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

```
t1, t2 = [], []

# below, we read data in from both files.
with open("table1.txt", "r") as f:
    t1 = f.read().split("\n")
with open("table2.txt", "r") as f:
    t2 = f.read().split("\n")

t12 = []
for i in t1:
    for j in t2:
        vals = i.split(":"), j.split(":") # we split up the key and value from each file.
        if vals[0][0] == vals[1][0]: # i.e. if the keys are the same
            t12.append(f"{vals[0][0]}: {vals[0][1]} | {vals[1][0]}: {vals[1][1]}\n") # create a new string that combines both values.

# writing to the new file
with open("tables_combined.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in t12:
        f.write(i)
```

Comment: I got the idea. Thanks. Your code however dumps this output:


`a:  1
b | a:  1
b`

Comment: @sam I've made appropriate edits. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, storage the pairs key-values from the files, removing whitespaces and '\n' (strip method), in a dictionary:

```
d = dict()
for path in file_paths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().replace(' ', '').split(':')
        if key in d.keys():
          d[key].append(value)
        else:
          d[key] = [value]
```

Then, print the values if there is more than 1 for the corresponding key:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if len(set(v)) > 1:
      s = [k + ':' + vv for vv in set(v)]
      s = ' | '.join(s)
      print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read both tables in dictionaries, iterate on the keys of the first one to find the keys that exist in the second one with different values, and build the output at the same time in a list comprehension:

```
 with open('table1.txt') as f:
    d1 = dict(line.strip().split(': ') for line in f)
    
with open('table2.txt') as f:
    d2 = dict(line.strip().split(': ') for line in f)
    
different = [f'{key}:{value} | {key}:{d2[key]}' 
                 for key, value in d1.items() 
                 if key in d2 and value!=d2[key]]

out = '\n'.join(different)
print(out)
# b:4 | b:5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably read each file into their own dictionary. So read the file, assign the letter as the key and the number as the value, meaning you get two dicts as such:

```
dict1 = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 4
}

dict2 = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
  "d": 5
}
```

Then you can loop through both dicts, comparing the keys and saving the odd ones out to a list or something similar. You could do this by doing something like this (if you're reasonably confident both dictionaries have the same letters as keys):

```
mismatched_values = []
for key in dict1:
  if dict1[key] != dict2[key]:
    mismatched_values.append(str(key) + ":" + str(dict1[key]) + "|" + str(key) + ":" + str(dict2[key])
```

Then you can output the `mismatched_values` parameteter to a txt file again.

Comment: The first data structure you have used is a `dict`ionary, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to read everything in python dictionaries and then compare them and print output in output.txt file

```
with open("a.txt", "r") as first_file:
    with open("b.txt", "r") as second_file:
        first_dict = {}
        second_dict = {}
        for i in first_file.readlines():
            first_dict[i.split(':')[0]] = i.split(':')[1].replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
        for i in second_file.readlines():
            second_dict[i.split(':')[0]] = i.split(':')[1].replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
with open("report.txt", "w+") as out_file:
    for i in first_dict.keys():
        if first_dict[i] != second_dict[i]:
            out_file.write("{a}:{b}|{a}:{c}\n".format(a=i, b=first_dict[i], c=second_dict[i]))
```